# How to solve the problem of flink sql batch task source operator Parallelism equals other operators

Tags: flink-sql

I need to read the data from the doris database and then process writing to other locations but due to database limitation the source Parallelism is a maximum of 3 but I set the global Parallelism to 8.
This leads to only three solts working in all the operators, and all the others are finish in advance
ex.:
[ex1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZ1ty.png)
[ex2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFOuT.png)

Read the data is very fast, the processing is very slow, how to improve the processing speed,
or how to implement rebalance with flink sql

Make all the solts really run